# How do I omit the words "type" and "value" from showing in my google sheet after running google script to get user data from AD?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, active-directory, google-sheets-api

i am new to Javascript and im currently trying to create a google sheet that lists all the users in the AD group + their phone numbers. however when i run this script below, the cell that should have the phone number in it has, "type=work, value=(000)123-4567 as well. i just want the phone number to be displayed by itself. how would I work around this? I'm sure im missing something simple

```
function writeToSpreadsheet(){
var values = [];
var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain:'companydomain.com'}).users; 
for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
  values.push([users[i].name.fullName, users[i].phones]); 

var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.userinfospreadsheet';
SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)
```

Im using this guide as a reference https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/listingdomainusernamesinaspreadsheet,

Comment: That must be a part of the string in `users[i].phones`. You can use a regular expression to extract just the number after `value=`.

Comment: `phones` is in that format because the user can have multiple phone numbers (work, home, mobile). What do you want to put in the sheet in that case?

Comment: We’re only going to use “work phone number” Home and mobile will remain blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that user's phones property is not a string but rather an object or list.
In order to get the nice list of the phone numbers you have to replace `users[i].phones` pushed to values array with function call `getPhones(users[i].phones)`
And this function should be something like this:

If user phones are array of objects `[{type: 'work', value: '(000)123-4567'}]`:

```
function getPhones(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(phoneObj) {
        return phoneObj.value;
    }).join(', ')
}
```

or if it is simply an object replce `users[i].phones` with `users[i].phones.value`

Comment: If it's an object it will convert to `[Object object]` as a string.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users

If I’m seeing it right, users[i].phones.value. Should work, but when I tried it earlier today. I remember getting an error

Comment: Scroll down, there is an explanation in the table about that phones value. It is an array of types `{customType: <string>, primary: <bool>, type: <string>, value: <string>}` so that function above will do the work

Answer (score 1):

[As the documentations states](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#User.FIELDS.phones), `phones` is an array of objects. The simplest way of handling them would be to use a function that converts them into a string:

```js
function generatePhonesCell(phones) {
  return phones
    .map(phone => {
      const value = phone.value
      const type = phone.type.replaceAll('_', ' ')
      return `${value} (${type})`
    })
    .join('\n')
}
```

This will list the phones in the form:

```
(000)123-4567 (home)
(000)765-4321 (work)
```

You only need to add them into your existing code:

```js
values.push([users[i].name.fullName, generatePhonesCell(users[i].phones || [])])
```

Comment: thanks i tried this but received "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefinedgeneratePhonesCell @ Code.gs:3
writeToSpreadsheet @ Code.gs:14. this happens when running this and the one below. would this be due to some of the users having a blank value for their phones in AD?

Comment: Yeah, my code expects it not be blank. Changing `generatePhonesCell(users[i].phones)` for `generatePhonesCell(users[i].phones || [])` should work.

Comment: Perfect, i actually took this and made the change to the code from Arek since we dont need to differentiate b/w the types. Works great now. Thanks very much.